# Which blowups of a smooth surface are smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Say $X$ is a smooth algebraic surface and $Z$ is some subscheme.  When is the blowup of $X$ along $Z$ smooth?

Comment: I don't think that there is a straightforward answer to this question, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21232/when-is-a-blow-up-non-singular/24074#24074

Comment: On a smooth *surface*, it is always smooth if $Z$ is reduced...  For non-reduced $Z$, the link Blup provided is useful.  On the other hand, there is Zariski factorization of complete (integrally closed) ideals through which the surface question should be more or less tractable.