# If the quotient of a local ring is regular, does that imply that the original ring must be regular?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a local ring and let $I\subset R$ be some nontrivial ideal. Are there conditions that we can place on $I$ so that if $R/I$ is regular, then so is $R$?

I am aware of the result that states: if $R$ is already a regular local ring, then $R/I$ is regular iff $I$ is generated by a subset of a regular system of parameters.  But I am wondering more about whether or not the regularity of $R$ itself can be determined by it's quotient $R/I$.

Background for this question: after reading the responses to the question [When is a blow-up non-singular?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21232/when-is-a-blow-up-non-singular) I am trying to work through the first argument in the second section of the paper ["On the smoothness of blow-ups."](http://www.informaworld.com/smpp/content~db=all~content=a780044502) I think the author uses the result that I am asking about when they state: "$S_P/f_i S_P$ is a regular local ring; since $f_i$ is a non-zero-divisor on $S_P$, it follows that $S_P$ is itself regular."  I am just trying to figure out where this result comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted result relies on the following elementary characterization of local regular rings:

> Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ and $x\in\mathfrak m-\mathfrak m^2$. Then $R$ is regular iff $R/(x)$ is regular and $x$ doesn't belong to any minimal prime.

Comment: Wow, that was a fast response to this question.  I guess this is a result that is very well known, that I must have just overlooked in my studies.  Thank you for the answer, and for the generalization and counterexample.

Comment: @QiL'8 Maybe I'm missing something: in your case, if, for instance, $r=1$ and $R/(x)$ is regular, then the embedding dimension of $R/(x)$ equals $\dim R/(x)=\dim R-1$. I think now it follows that $x\notin\mathfrak m^2$. (What I want to say is that in the end the elements $x_i$ turn out to be outside of $\mathfrak m^2$, although you are not assuming this.)